# How to get unique values from comma separated values field?

Tags: mysql

I've a column in my table where i store the values as comma separated values,

Now i'm in need of listing all the unique values from that field/column..

How can i do this?

I'm using php..

Comment: Well, if you want to show unique values, you may be better off not storing your data as comma separated values :) Anyway, what language are you using for your business logic? This may be easier to do in the php/java/... code.

Comment: Now you know why comma separated values are a bad idea in a DBMS. Start over again and normalize your data.

Comment: I can't make much changes to the old data.. So i'm thinking of fetching unique values using the array_unique and store them in a separate table as tags and then just use the current table structure as it is.. So when i need unique values i can directly fetch from the tags table and when anything new is added then i can add them to them and also easily list all the tags frm a single column itself.. Is that ok??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noway with mysql alone if you are using php then
best bet is to retrieve the field and then use php to get your distinct values.  `explode()` is a good approach, and then you could use `array_unique` to remove duplicate values.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

or

You could normalize your database

Answer (score 0):

Storing multiple (comma-separated) values in one field is not a good database design, you should store that values in other table. In that case you'd be able to use GROUP BY SQL statement.
In current situation you should select all data from table, explode() it, sort it, and drop out duplicates, which will take much more time.

Answer (score 0):

what, nobody storing keywords as comma separated data in the DB?

Unfortunately, the only way to quickly do it is to write a php script to explode values and than do count on distinct values in the array.