# How to select the unique values of a comma separated values in MySQL field?

Tags: mysql, database, select

Something like this:

```
Select UNIQUE_VALUES('1,2,3,5,3,4,2,1,2,3,1,4') as CSVUnique
```

The result of this will be:

```
CSVUnique
1,2,3,5,4
```

Thanks!

Comment: Read up on `SELECT DISTINCT` @ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: @MikePurcell - OP wants distinct values from a single comma-separated string, not distinct row values from a column.

Comment: Wait, he is actually storing values like this? I thought it was a beginner question, figured he was selecting from multiple rows. Yikes.

Answer (score 6):

No way with mysql for getting unique like this way.

First it's bad that you storing values like this way. You should use parent child tables for storing such data instead of storing com,a separated values. Or should filter such duplicates before inserting.

Normalize your database.

get values from table and use php  `explode()` , and  use `array_unique` to remove duplicate values.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537838/how-to-get-unique-values-from-comma-separated-values-field

Comment: There are ways (with MySQL alone) to get unique values. But +1 for advice to normalize.

Comment: @ypercube :Yes can try with stored procedure. But My intention here is the way posted in question UNIQUE_VALUES(...).... not in mysql

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way

```
CREATE TABLE t
( vals VARCHAR (100));
INSERT INTO t VALUES('1,2,3,5,3,4,2,1,2,3,1,4');


SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(vals, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1)) val
FROM
  t
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6) n
  ON LENGTH(REPLACE(vals, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(vals)-n.digit;
```

[See it working](http://rextester.com/AWCMKT87372)