# how to remove duplicate data using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have my data is like this in table.

```
 name  day1  day2 day3 
 Anand  P     NA   NA 
 Anand  NA    P    NA 
 Anand  NA   NA  P 


I want result like this

name  day1 day2 day3
Anand P    P     P
```

Group by clause is giving only first row data. 
    Please suggest me mysql query. you can assume table name as att_table.

Comment: what is NA? Is that null?

Comment: if you used 1/0 instead of P / NA, you could then use sum() with group by, which would give you the result you want.

Comment: what are the values contain in the fields?? Int or string???

Comment: **Group by clause is giving only first row data** What aggregation function did you use with `GROUP BY`?

Comment: i think you need to use `COALESCE`.

Comment: _Closesly_ related to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/36472820/5830574

Comment: @Barmar I guess the OP used `max`. At least he said so in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472820/how-to-remove-duplicates-in-mysql-query#comment60557659_36473225)

Comment: Is there a difference between this question and your last question?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NULLIF` to replace the `NA` value with `NULL`, and then use `MAX()` to get the non-null value within each group.

```
SELECT name, MAX(NULLIF(day1, 'NA')) AS day1, MAX(NULLIF(day2, 'NA')) AS day2, MAX(NULLIF(day3, 'NA')) AS day2
FROM att_table
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(day1),
  GROUP_CONCAT(day2),
  GROUP_CONCAT(day3)
FROM att_table
GROUP BY name;
```

If `'NA'` is a string and not SQL's `NULL` value, try this instead:

```
SELECT
  name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day1 = 'NA', NULL, day1)),
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day2 = 'NA', NULL, day2)),
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(day3 = 'NA', NULL, day3))
FROM att_table
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: missing `GROUP BY`

Comment: Nope, the GROUP BY clause serves no purpose here.

Comment: If you don't use `GROUP BY`, you'll combine all the rows for all the different users.

Comment: Then use `where name = Anand`

Comment: Why do you think he only wants the result for one user, not to do it for all the users?

Comment: Ok good point, seeing things with that angle it makes more sense.